# Objects and Lists with Merge Sort

Tags: python-2.7

I have a duck Class, such that each Duck object created contains wingspan and weight field variables. Each of these should be initialized randomly for every duck. Wingspans should be initialized to a random float in the range [80.0,100.0]cm. Weight should be initialized randomly in the range [0.7,1.6]kg. I have

```
import random
class Duck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.wingspan = round(random.uniform(80.0, 100.0), 1)
        self.weight = round(random.uniform(0.7,1.6), 2)
```

The second part is asking me to write a function called makeFlock() that takes an integer parameter, n, and returns a list of n Duck objects.

```
def makeFlock(n):
    flock = []
    for _ in range(n):
        flock.append(Duck())
    return(flock)
```

Lastly, I need to write a function called sortDucks() that takes a list of Duck objects as a parameter, and returns the list sorted in ascending order according to the ducks wingspan. A hint given is to use the merge sort algorithm but I'm not quite sure of how to do this. Can anyone explain?
*Can't use any built in functions

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

Firstly, I changed the  `makeFlock` into List comprehensions for simplicity.

Secondly for the sorting I'm using the `sorted` function - you can read more [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)

```
import random
class Duck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.wingspan = round(random.uniform(80.0, 100.0), 1)
        self.weight = round(random.uniform(0.7,1.6), 2)

def makeFlock(n):
    return [Duck() for _ in range(n)]

def sortDucks(ducks):
    return sorted(ducks, key=lambda duck: duck.weight) 

flock = makeFlock(5)
sorted_flock = sortDucks(flock)

for duck in sorted_flock:
    print duck.weight
```

If you cannot use the `sorted` function, this is something I quickly wrote. Let me know if you want me to explain it.

```
def sortDucks(ducks):
    # list with the first duck inside
    sorted_ducks = [ducks[0]]
    for d in range(1, len(ducks)):
        # place the second duck into pos 0
        sorted_ducks.insert(0, ducks[d])
        # Loop over the sorted_ducks list and place the duck where the next duck has a larger weight
        for s in range(1, len(sorted_ducks)):
            if ducks[d].weight < sorted_ducks[s].weight:
                break
            else:
                sorted_ducks.pop(s-1)
                sorted_ducks.insert(s, ducks[d])
    return sorted_ducks
```

Comment: forgot to add I can't use any built in functions

Comment: @teeth have edited the answer, let me know if you want me to explain it further?

Comment: thank you very much! that was very clear, I understand now